# Installing AVP 2010 without Steam

Tags: steam

The initial install of AVP 2010 worked fine with Steam. After reinstalling the OS and downloading and installing Steam, I can't install AVP 2010 from disc again.

I don't want to download the game because of limited bandwidth, and tired of downloading 15 Gb every time.

So question is how to install AVP 2010 without Steam interfering? I have installed 5 times again, yet for some reason Steam doesn't see the installation.

When I pop the CD in, it has a "Play Game" option, however when I click on it Steam thinks it isn't installed and wants to download the game again.

Or if there is a way how can I make Steam see the installation?

I have also tried the Steam retail install option, where I execute the install command from run dialog, but that doesn't work for some reason.

Also there is no downloadable content to delete, any ideas?

Comment: you could try starting the download in Steam, pausing it, exiting Steam, copying the contents of the install from the retail CD into the folder Steam is downloading the game to, logging back into Steam and resuming the download, see if that detects the files...

Comment: @kalina I'm not sure how that'd work. There are 2 discs

Comment: didn't you say you had already installed the game to your PC?

Comment: 1) Is AVP listed in your Steam Library? 2) Is it dark (not installed) or light (installed)? 3) Are you sure it's not just updating? What you're describing is normal Steam behaviour for an installed game that has new patches, is why I'm asking.

Comment: @kalina That's right. Gotcha now. Will try it

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is dark/grayed out

Comment: I've tried it.. but it still wants to download another 14gb worth of data. Very big for an update no?

Comment: could be that it just won't work without downloading it once you've activated it on your Steam account

Comment: F**k Steam. Anyway, I appreciate the help. Thanks lads.

Comment: Generally, if Steam can find a game, it will choose to validate it rather than install it.  Steam games are generally installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steamapps\common\ on Windows (each in their own folder).  However, Steam may package the game differently than the retail release.